# External JavaScript Library adding inline styles "Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive"

Tags: javascript, security, content-security-policy, inline-styles

I have implemented Content Security Policy (`script-src` and `style-src` directives) for my application using csp nonce approach.

While testing the application I have found out that charts are not working fine.

On further analysis i came to know that "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/51/js/jsapi_compiled_ui_module.js" file from charts library is adding inline styles while showing data in charts which is the reason csp violations are coming up and data is not being shown properly in the charts (because the inline styles will not work if we implement csp's "style-src").

I have tried adding "unsafe-hashes" to `style-src` directive in csp with the hash values being added in the policy and the charts are working fine and csp violations are not raised. But, we wanted to resolve this issue with out adding "unsafe-hashes" key word in the policy because it is generally considered as unsafe to use "unsafe-hashes/inline" in csp.

I need to know is there any possible way to resolve the csp violations and csp to allow inline styles for this one specific case?

Answer (score 0):

The actual treat of style-src with 'unsafe-inline' is covered well here: https://scotthelme.co.uk/can-you-get-pwned-with-css/

You choices would likely be:

- Replace the component adding inline styles
- Add 'unsafe-inline' and restrict all other parts of your policy
- Add hashes for each and every variant of the inline styles

The feasibility of the last option depends on the number of variations of inline styles produced. As the component adding styles is not doing this in a CSP friendly way, CSP nonces are probably not an option.